# How to fix the X Window System error coming when running a c++ GTK program

Tags: gtk, c++, gdb

I am getting an error while running a program written in c++ in GTK. The program stops when this error appear. I am a beginner and i have no idea what to do for this. The error is as follows.

```
(main:4082): Gdk-ERROR **: 15:33:56.607: The program 'main' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadLength (poly request too large or internal Xlib length erro'.
  (Details: serial 56298 error_code 16 request_code 139 (RENDER) minor_code 23)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I have used a function to run asynchronously in the program. I think that this error might be because of that.
The function is as follows.

```
void asyncFunction (){
  while(1){
    counter = counter +1;
    
    //cout << counter<<endl;
    string str = to_string(counter);
    const char * bn = str.c_str();
    gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(Entry_length) , bn);
    sleep(2);
  }
}
```

And i have added the following line in the main.

```
future<void> fn = async(launch::async, asyncFunction);
```

I found this in the internet and i dont have much idea about this.

Can anyone please help me to fix this error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely not related to any behaviour of your program code but caused by input data and/or some of your font configuration.

I encountered the same error when starting gitk in a repo that contained the "" character in a commit message.

Based on [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2013495#p2013495) I ran

```bsh
fc-list -f "%{family}\n" > font-list.txt
wc -l font-list.txt          # 1559 lines on my system
script screen-capture.txt    # Starts a new shell and writes all output to the file
cat font-list | while read FONT; do echo "$FONT"; env LC_ALL=C xfd -fa "$FONT" & PID=$!; sleep 3; kill $PID;  done
exit                         # Exits the extra shell
diff -u font-list.txt screen-capture.txt
```

and the diff command then produced the following output

```
...
@@ -917,6 +918,12 @@
 Roboto
 drmsc17
 Noto Color Emoji
+X Error of failed request:  BadLength (poly request too large or internal Xlib length error)
+  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RENDER)
+  Minor opcode of failed request:  20 (RenderAddGlyphs)
+  Serial number of failed request:  196
+  Current serial number in output stream:  445
+bash: kill: (2056553) - Ingen slik prosess
 Tlwg Typewriter
 Noto Sans Gurmukhi,Noto Sans Gurmukhi ExtraCondensed Thin
 PakType Tehreer
...
```

So clearly the font "Noto Color Emoji" is the one that is triggering problems here. I uninstalled it by running

```bsh
$ fc-list -f "%{family}|%{file}\n" | grep 'Noto Color Emoji'
Noto Color Emoji|/usr/share/fonts/google-noto-emoji/NotoColorEmoji.ttf
$ rpm -qf /usr/share/fonts/google-noto-emoji/NotoColorEmoji.ttf
google-noto-emoji-color-fonts-20200916-3.fc35.noarch
$ sudo dnf remove google-noto-emoji-color-fonts-20200916
```

and after that I no longer got the error.

(For Ubuntu `rpm` and `dnf` should be replaced with some variant of `dpkg` and `apt` as far as I know)

---

The extra LC_ALL was to suppress an additional message "Warning: Missing charsets in String to FontSet conversion" triggered by my locale.